# Why isn't text box passing info into variable?

Tags: powershell, ssh, textbox

Ok i almost have this working the way i need it. Last thing... instead of changing the user name in the script for each one of my techs... i want to use a Text box that they can input the username.. the way i have it set up now connects to the switch but its asking for a password not a PIN&PASSCODE like it would normally if i left the username in the script.

```
#############
# Variables #
#############

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$username = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label


###########################################################
#                        FORM LAYOUT                      #
###########################################################
$CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $label1.Text = $combobox1.SelectedItem.Address.ToString()
  
}

$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 292
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 266
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

###################
# Label1 Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 125
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 5

###################
# Label2 Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point3 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point3.X = 130
$System_Drawing_Point3.Y = 50

###################
# Button Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point1 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point1.X = 157
$System_Drawing_Point1.Y = 140

######################
# Textbox1 Location  #
######################

$System_Drawing_Point2 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point2.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point2.Y = 110

#############
# Control's #
#############

$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Text = 'Select Switch'
$label2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point3
$label2.Text = 'Enter NEMA Account'
$form1.Controls.Add($label1)
$form1.Controls.Add($combobox1) 
$form1.Controls.Add($button1)
$form1.Controls.Add($username)
$username.Location = $System_Drawing_Point2
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point1
$button1.Text = 'Connect'
$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh $username@$($label1.Text)})
$form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load)
$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged)
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

particularly this line... `$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh $username@$($label1.Text)})` ***NOT WORKING.***

`$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh domain\myusername@$($label1.Text)})` ***Works***

its acting like the username isn't being applied? Am I on the right path?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: if $username is the variable which contains the textbox control, you'd want $username.Text to get the contents.  Maybe  --->  $button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh $($username.Text)@$($label1.Text)})

Comment: Hmm.. i tried that but i get this error...

`error: Get address information failed: No such host is known.`

Comment: update: if i leave the textbox empty and select a switch... it connects to the switch but asks for a password. so its seeing the box is blank. the above error is when i put in the username in the textbox. very strange.....

Comment: Try adding some logging into your event handler to make sure you're getting the expected values in your variables - e.g. this ```$button1.Add_Click({write-host "username = '$($username.Text)'"; write-host "label1.Text = '$($label1.Text)'"})
```. If the output from that looks right then it'll help narrow down the problem to elsewhere...

Comment: Maybe try this line instead?

$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command "ssh $username@$($label1.Text)"})

Comment: I solved the Issue... just created another drop down box with the Name and username.. so the button now works like this `$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh -l $($label2.Text)@$($label1.Text)})`  i needed the -l switch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this...

> Why isn't text box passing info into variable?

... well, you are not using a textbox at all.

This is not correct...

```
$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh $username@$($label1.Text)})
```

... you are literally asking for the label display text not what is selected in the combobox.

From a UX/UI perspective, taking the text from a user-interactive form element, and assigning that text to a UX label, then calling the resultant text from that label element is not proper or prudent.

You take the text content from the user-interactive form element (textbox, combobox, datagrid, etc.)

You don't use label control to host user interactive provided data. They are just banner info to indicate what should be entered/selected in user-interactive form element.

For example:

```
# sample form with, no label elements, just interactive elements, combobox selection to richtextbox

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

$ComboBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$ComboBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,10)
$ComboBox.Items.AddRange(@('One','Two'))


$RichTextBox          = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox
$RichTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40)

$Form                 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Controls.Add($ComboBox)
$Form.Controls.Add($RichTextBox)

$ComboBox.Add_TextChanged({

    # Code here
    switch($ComboBox.Text){
    "One" {$RichTextBox.Text = "This is one"}
    "Two" {$RichTextBox.Text = "This is two"}

    }

})

$Form.ShowDialog()
```

So a quick fix to your GUI just to the interactive results is this...

```
#############
# Variables #
#############

$form1     = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$label1    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$button1   = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$username  = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$label2    = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label


###########################################################
#                        FORM LAYOUT                      #
###########################################################
$CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $combobox1.SelectedItem

}

$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 292
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 266
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

###################
# Label1 Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 125
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 5

###################
# Label2 Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point3 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point3.X = 130
$System_Drawing_Point3.Y = 50

###################
# Button Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point1 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point1.X = 157
$System_Drawing_Point1.Y = 140

######################
# Textbox1 Location  #
######################

$System_Drawing_Point2 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point2.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point2.Y = 110

#############
# Control's #
#############

$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Text     = 'Select Switch'

$combobox1.Items.AddRange(@('Switch1','Switch2'))

$label2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point3
$label2.Text     = 'Enter NEMA Account'

$form1.Controls.Add($label1)
$form1.Controls.Add($combobox1) 
$form1.Controls.Add($button1)
$form1.Controls.Add($username)

$username.Location = $System_Drawing_Point2

$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point1
$button1.Text     = 'Connect'
$button1.Add_Click({
    "$($username.Text)@$($combobox1.Text)" | Out-Host
})

# $form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load) # you are not using this anywhere, so, not needed.

$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged)

$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```

Yet, I have to say, you really should be using a Drag and drop designer to help you layout this UX/UI effort, vs hard coding it. There are other things that from a UX/UI best practice that are out of place.

Take a look at using:  https://poshgui.com, or using the free Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition, and there are a few others. See also, the 'Windows Forms' and 'WPF forms' development videos on Youtube for further examples/guidance.

Comment: Thank you for the very well detailed answer. I should have just copied the whole code and took out the identifying info.. I got it to work by creating another drop down box..and selecting the username that way. so the connect button would look look like this..

`$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh -l $($label2.Text)@$($label1.Text)})`

i didnt include the code for : # $form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load). but that converts the selected item in the dropdown box to a string. in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete working code, feel free to use this for yourself just change the values under switch information and nema account.

code:

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null

#############
# Variables #
#############

$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$combobox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$combobox2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$label1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$label2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button


##################################################################
#            SWITCH INFORMATION - SWitch Combo Box               #
##################################################################
$FormEvent_Load = {
##################################################################################################################### Basement
$combobox1.DisplayMember = 'Name'
    $combobox1.Items.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name' = '******BASEMENT******'
            })
    $combobox1.DisplayMember = 'Name'
    $combobox1.Items.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name' = 'GA- GC105C'
            'Address' = [ipaddress]::Parse('10.10.10.100')
        })
  
}

##################################################################
#         NEMA INFORMATION - NEMA COMBOBOX                       #
##################################################################

$FormEvent_Load2 = {
$combobox2.DisplayMember = 'Name'
    $combobox2.Items.Add(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            'Name' = 'Aaron'
            'UserName' = ('domain\useracct')
        })
        }

###########################################################
#                        FORM LAYOUT                      #
###########################################################
$CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged = {
    $label1.Text = $combobox1.SelectedItem.Address.ToString()
    }
  
$CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged2 = {
    $label2.Text = $combobox2.SelectedItem.Username.ToString()
    }

$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState

$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 292
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 266
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size

###################
# Label1 Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 125
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 5

###################
# Label2 Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point3 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point3.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point3.Y = 85

###################
# Button Location #
###################

$System_Drawing_Point1 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point1.X = 157
$System_Drawing_Point1.Y = 140

#######################
# combo box2 Location #
#######################

$System_Drawing_Point2 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point2.X = 150
$System_Drawing_Point2.Y = 110


#############
# Control's #
#############

$form1.Controls.Add($combobox1)
$form1.Controls.Add($combobox2)
$form1.Controls.Add($label1)
$form1.Controls.Add($label2)
$form1.Controls.Add($button1)
$combobox2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point2
$label1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$label1.Text = 'Select Switch:'
$label2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point3
$label2.Text = 'Select NEMA Account:'
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point1
$button1.Text = 'Connect'
$button1.Add_Click({cmd /c start powershell -Command ssh -l $($label2.Text)@$($label1.Text)})
$form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load)
$form1.add_Load($FormEvent_Load2)
$ComboBox1.add_SelectedIndexChanged($CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged)
$ComboBox2.add_SelectedIndexChanged($CBEvent_SelectedIndexChanged2)
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null
```